# Is Russia able to influence Israel?

Tags: russian-federation, immigration, israel

Is Russia able to influence the affairs of Israeli politics and foreign policy through the Russian immigrants in Israel?

Comment: Similarly we could Ask: "Is Israel able to influence the affairs of American politics and foreign policy through their dual citizens in the USA?"

Comment: @KeithMcClary, I know the answer. The answer is YES. So, I don't bother.

Comment: can you explain this question?

Answer (score 6):

the answer to the specified question is no. during the 90s and beginning of 2000s, [close to one million people from former soviet union immigrated to israel.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990s_post-Soviet_aliyah#:%7E:text=Approximately%20148%2C000%20more%20Soviet%20immigrants,1994%2C%20and%2064%2C848%20in%201995.)  they are not agents of Russia and are not behaving as homogeneous community.
whether Russia was able to influence the affairs of Israeli politics through other means was never asserted or proven.

Comment: As people who emigrated and found reasons to leave, is it known what their sentiment towards Russia's government are?  for example, Cuban American sentiments towards Cuba's government are overwhelmingly, or at least largely, negative.  On the other hand, one presumes UK immigrants to the US to be positive in general.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher - I would hazard a guess that the opinions of most Russian Jews in Israel toward the current Russian government are fairly negative. But I cannot be sure.